# Where to store notification component to be visible in every page ? React custom notification

Tags: reactjs

I have my component for notification

For now this component is only visible in my home page. What I need?
I need to be visible in every route, example if I want to change route to be visible in different route, where to put this component?

Right now this  is inside Home page and will be triggered in some case. Work good but when. go to different page is not visible..

Where to set this component to be visible in every page?
I am try inside

```
const root = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(root);

render(
  <StrictMode>
    <NotificationComponent />
    <App />
  </StrictMode>,
  root,
);
```

but this is not solution....

Comment: Probably using [context api](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) , wrap the App with the provider and pass the visibility setter to its children, from there you can update the notification state from any of the provider's children.

Comment: How to do it ?? Code example please. Minimal

Answer (score 0):

if you want your notification component to visible in every page, use it or import it in your **APP.js**

Answer (score 0):

Using [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), wrap the `App` with the provider and pass the visibility setter to its children, from there you can update the notification state from any of the provider's children.

**Notificationprovider**

```
import { render } from 'less'
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react'
export const NotificationCtx = createContext()

function NotificationProvider({ children }) {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false)
  return <NotificationCtx.Provider value={{ setIsVisible }}>
    {children}
    {isVisible && <div>Notification</div>}
  </NotificationCtx.Provider>

}
```

**index**

```
render(
  <NotificationProvider>
    <App />
  </NotificationProvider>, root
)
```

**App**

```
import { useContext } from 'react'
import { NotificationCtx } from "yourpath/to/provider"

function App() {
  const { setIsVisible } = useContext(NotificationCtx)

  return <button onClick={() => setIsVisible(true)}></button>
}
```

You can access the `setIsVisible` from App's children using useContext.